# Using PDO For Adding Comments

Tags: php, pdo

For a side project I'm working on, users can comment/share their opinions on certain subjects and etc. While inserting works fine, how do I make it so that user's can post comments such as

> "This is a test comment. I'm. You're. They're"

without the prepared statement inserting this instead:

> "This is a test comment. I\'m. You\'re. They\'re"

Is there any way to insert comments and etc. like such with prepared statements without the slashes?

Comment: Do you really still have magic quotes enabled?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDO or prepared statements, but rather your PHP configuration.

Comment: Ah, those sneaky magic quotes -__-" Completely forget about them..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought i had heard the last of Magic Quotes

You need to disable them

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: not [this kitten](http://s692.photobucket.com/albums/vv281/FormulaGTA/Misc%20Pictures/?action=view&current=kitten-gun.jpg&newest=1)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have added the slashes yourself via an escaping or other string function, it is due to the [magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes_gpc) php setting. Disable it.

Answer (score 1):

When using prepared statements, there is no need to use whatever escaping function like PDO::quote, addslashes, mysql_real_escape_string and such.
If you are using one, just quit it.